# Hiberante and SQL Server Column name

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, sql-server-2005

I have a database that uses "-" in it's columns names.

Example

```
system-test-id
```

I mapped the table in Hibernate, but when I try to select all, for example, I get this error:

```
Invalid column name "system"
```

Notice that only the first word is taken as column name.

Option show_sql in hibernate shows me this:

```
select this_.system-test-id as system1_0_0_ (...)
```

**EDIT**

I had to add \" in the column name on mapping:

```
@Id
@Column(name="\"system-test-id\"")
private long systemTestId;
```

Comment: If it's an option, I would simply rename your columns with underscores.

Comment: Then you column name was "system-test-id" not just system-test-id !

Comment: Nope. When I created the database in the SQL Server interface I didn't put any quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Column(name="\"system-test-id\"") is the JPA defined way to handle quoted identifiers.

Hibernate has a little more friendly syntax using batck-ticks: @Column(name="`system-test-id`")

The back-ticks (`) or embedded double-quotes indicate the identifier should be quoted and are replaced with dialect-specific identifier quoting.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the difference between

```
create table #t
(
    [id-Column] int
)
```

and

```
create table #t
(
    id-Column int
)
```